# How can i convert full calendar to real time using node.js

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, node-modules

I'm using php and javascript to render full calendar, but i want to make it real time with node.js, so that i can show event as soon as they occur. I have not used node.js before. How can i achieve this in node.js (any link of tutorial), also can i use shared hosting for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case you could have a `setInterval` function in your page which tells fullCalendar to refetch the events from your server (via AJAX) every minute or two - but beware of overloading the server with lots of requests.

However if you want something which is literally real-time where data is pushed from the server to the browser, then you would need to use WebSockets or Server-Sent Events (SSE). 
FullCalendar doesn't support these directly so you'd have to have some other code in your page to listen for data from the server and then change that data on the calendar

As for hosting, you wouldn't need anything special for the AJAX-based solution. For WebSockets or SSE you'd need to check whether the hosting company's platform can support that. You should be able to read it on their documentation / advertising, or check with their sales/support teams.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't want to use ajax. Can the above task  achieved in node.js if yes can u provide a link of any helpful content.

Comment: @user3653474 NodeJS definitely has implementations of a websockets server which you could use, and also I would think of server-sent events. I am not a NodeJS expert and so I would not like to recommend anything specific, but a simple google search for "nodeJS websockets" will soon give you lots of interesting information and implementations.